# Top n percent top n%

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I do have the following code.

```
    SQL> select * from student_gpa;

    SSN                    GPA
    --------------- ----------
   22222                    3
   11111                    4
   55555                    3
   33333                    4
   44444                    3
```

I do have this function to get the top two gpa score rows.

SQL> select * from (select ssn, gpa from student_gpa order by gpa desc) where  rownum <= 2;

```
     SSN                    GPA
    --------------- ----------
    11111                    4
    33333                    4
```

My question is what function do I use to get the top n% of the GPA score.  For example, Since I have two individuals with a GPA of 4, dense rank would return 11111 occupying row 1 and 22222 occupying row 2. I was actually looking for a function say that calculates 5% of the GPA score and the returned value would be both 11111 and 22222. The 5% function SHOULD NOT return 11111 only. Even if I had more entries that had gpa of 4, the 5% function would still return all rows that had gpa of 4.Thanks

Comment: :both the entry in top means? how you want the result please edit your question ,i think i have misunderstood your question ,please verify my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
WITH     got_analytics     AS
(
     SELECT     ssn, gpa
     ,     ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY  gpa  DESC)     AS r_num
     ,     COUNT (*)     OVER ()                                AS n_rows 
     FROM  student_gpa   
)
SELECT       ssn, gpa
FROM       got_analytics 
WHERE       r_num     <= ROUND (n_rows * 12/*insert here your n%*/ / 100)
ORDER BY  gpa     DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 create table student_gpa(ssn number,gpa number);

 insert into student_gpa values(1111,4);
 insert into student_gpa values(2222,4);
 insert into student_gpa values(3333,3);
 insert into student_gpa values(4444,2);

 select ssn,gpa from(
   select ssn, gpa,dense_rank() over (order by gpa desc) rn from student_gpa
     )
   where rn =1;

    ssn   gpa
   --------------
   1111   4
   2222   4
```

Comment: Thanks Guarav Soni. But  actually I want to get the percentage of the total. I was looking at rank function but I don't want to explicitly return the first two rows. I want a function that explicitly returns the top 5%. I think the count function too is needed. I'm just not sure how to put in the function. Thanks.

Comment: @user1655056:please mention the output what you want.

Comment: @GuaravSoni Since I have two individuals with a gpa of 4, dense rank would return  11111 occupying row 1 and 22222 occupying row 2. I was actually looking for a function say that calculates 5% and the returned value would be both 11111 and 22222. The 5% function SHOULD NOT return 11111 only.  Even if I had more entries that had gpa of 4, the 5% function would still return all rows that had gpa of 4.Thanks

Comment: @user1655056:5% of what ?please give me a detailed explaination ,then after someone will help you .and please edit your question

Comment: @GuaravSoni 5% of the top N. In this case top 5% of the top gpa scores. Thanks for the reminder too.

Comment: @user1655056:suppose there are 10 people of same gpa ,then how will you distinguish which one to pick?

Comment: I actually want to return all of them as having GPA of 4. I don't intend to pick any of them out

Comment: @user1655056:so how is percentage matter here ,just change my answer,if there are 4 people of 4 gpa ,my query will return those four records

Comment: @GuaravSoni. It is of a big database that picks out the 5%.This is just a little snap short. It is for an assignment too

Comment: @user1655056:m sorry i am not getting your question ,and even your 5% theory ,i am having geninue question that if there are 20 ssn of same grade,how will you get 5% of it ,and if yes on what basis,you have also mentioned that you want all of them having grade .Sorry :(

Comment: @GuaravSoni. I have edited the question. I have used rank and I am trying to put count too. I have seen it being used on server I am trying to use it on oracle.

Answer (score 0):

First 30 percent with 2 selects:

```
select ssn,gpa from(
select ssn, gpa,rank() over (order by gpa asc) as rn, count(*) over() as cnt
from student_gpa
)
where rn < 0.3*cnt ;
```

Solution with 4 selects and rownum (very ugly):

```
select ssn,gpa from(
select ssn, gpa
from student_gpa
)
where rownum < 0.3*(select count(*) from (select ssn, gpa from student_gpa));
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, Top-N Queries like that are usually done using analytic functions, such as NTILE, so in your case:

```sql
WITH     got_tenth_gpa     AS
(
     SELECT     ssn, gpa
     ,     NTILE (10) OVER (ORDER BY gpa DESC)     AS tenth_gpa
     FROM     student_gpa
)
SELECT       ssn, gpa
FROM       got_tenth_gpa
WHERE       tenth_gpa     = 10
ORDER BY  gpa     DESC;
```