# Top N% students oracle

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Top n percent top n%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825196/top-n-percent-top-n)

```
 SQL> select ssn, gpa from (select ssn, gpa,
 rank() over(partition by ssn order by gpa desc) as rank,
 count(*) over(partition by ssn) as no_students

 SQL> from students_gpa)

  Error
                 *
```

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: missing expression

I am trying to get the top 5% of students with a GPA of 4. Since I have two students with a GPA of 4, I want to report both students and not just one one 1 student who occupies the first row. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are trying to copy and paste a SQL statement that has multiple blank lines into SQL*Plus.  If so, you would either need to remove the blank lines before copying and pasting or you would need to run the SQL*Plus command `set sqlblanklines on` in SQL*Plus before pasting the query that includes blank lines.